# How can you access cookies on a static S3 site behind a CloudFront distribution?

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, amazon-s3, cookies, amazon-cloudfront

So I'm trying to deploy my website which works well when in a local environment, but when it is deployed to Cloudfront, it can't seem to access cookies.

My frontend tech stack is as follows: Angular site hosted on S3, cloudfront distribution in front of it, custom domain name with a valid ssl certificate.

When the user navigates to the login page, they can successfully submit the forum, and the server responds with a JWT token in the `Set-Cookie` header.

[image: Set-Cookie header]

After this though, in the angular site it says that the `access-token` cookie does not exist. The strange part here is that on subsequent requests, the `access-token` cookie is in fact forwarded back to the backend. (In the image below, the login button was pressed again, so the response cookie is the same as the request cookie.)

[image: A screenshot of the token being received and sent through the network.]

I've ensured that `HttpOnly` is not set, and that the frontend and backend are both hosted under the same root domain `frontend.root.com` and `api.root.com`.

Cloudfront has been configured to forward the access-token cookie:

*cache policy*:
[image: Cache key settings: headers - none, cookies - none, query strings - none]

*origin request policy* (note that it still did not work when I had this set to forward all cookies and not just the access token):
[image: Origin request settings: headers - all viewer headers, cookies - access-token, query strings - all]

*Response headers settings*:
[image: CORS settings for response headers]

So in my angular site, after the `/login` api call resolves, I use the `ngx-cookie-service` to check and try to retrieve the cookie.

```
this.cookieService.check('access-token'); // checks if it exists, returns false
this.cookieService.get('access-token'); // returns '' meaning the cookie does not exist
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue and access the cookies from within my angular site? I can provide more information on my configurations if needed. Thanks!

Comment: is the cookie being set on the navigation request, but you can't apply it to the ajax request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can barely make out in the screenshot the Cookies have the domain set as something starting with `a` suggesting that it is `api.root.com`, most importantly it is not `frontend.root.com` and not `root.com`.

The server needs to set the domain of the cookie to `root.com` for it to be available to all subdomains of it.